# Marketo how to change template used by page

Tags: marketo

I am building a page / site using Marketo, Im really struggling with the GUI and need someone to explain to me how to change the template file used by a Guided Template.

I have cloned a template and a page and wish to use it as a test however i cannot seem to change the template assigned to a page thus when i update the template it updates the live version too

Answer (score 1):

The thing with guided templates is that the content created on the page using the variables or editable regions are unique to that template. Even though you created a duplicate and the content and those regions' IDs are the same, Marketo is not smart enough to map the content created in one template to the content in another template.

You can see this in action just by changing the ID of an editable region in a template, then go back to the page using that template and you'll find that the content for that region was lost. To you, it's the same region, but to Marketo it is a totally different one now. So even if you could swap templates for a page, you'd lose all the content because of this.

Unfortunately for now, you have to create a new page using the desired template.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue also, it seems to be a terrible limitation.